# Wireshark "follow TCP" decompressed?

Tags: http, tcp, wireshark

I've seen tutorials online where is possible to use "Follow TCP stream" in Wireshark and have the data decompressed in the pop up. My Wireshark shows me data compressed in the pop up.

When I looked online I only found work arounds , not a solution.

I know how to export objects or decompress it after saving it on disk but I would like to have it in a readable format in the "Follow TCP stream" pop up.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that decompressing was really done inside "follow tcp stream" and not for example by viewing a HTTP response body? Could you add a reference to such a tutorial which showed this?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPgCZwj446o at 1:02

Comment: This is not a compressed response at 1:02, thus there is nothing to decompress.

Comment: Why do my "Follow TCP Stream" shows only the header in plain text, the rest is compressed ?

Comment: Because you probably have a compressed response body, contrary to the example in the video. Have a look at "Content-Encoding: gzip" or similar in the request header: you don't find this in the video but you'll probably find it in your pcap file.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you